# Filter DE via SSJS an store Data in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

In my Cloudpage i use SSJS to filter a special row of my Data Exention.

```
    email = Request.GetFormField("email");
    hash = Request.GetFormField("hash");

    accountDE = DataExtension.Init("sfUserAccount");

      filter = {
       LeftOperand: {
        Property:  "emailAddress",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value:   email
       },
       LogicalOperator:"AND",
       RightOperand: {
        Property:  "Id",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value:   hash
       }
      };

    var data  = accountDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter); 
    // var dataLength  = data.length;

    if (dataLength > 0) {
         Write(data[0].fieldname);
         Variable.SetValue("valuename", data[0].fieldname);
    endif
```

Unfortunately, i don't know how to store a special field of the data extention in my Variable.SetValue. How can i get the information of data?
I don't get any result for Write(data[0].fieldname); etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's pretty simple in SSJS if you know some JavaScript. you just need to create a variable and assign those variable to DataExtension fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
  Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1"); 
  var email, hash, accountDE, data, dataLength, FirstName, LastName; 

    email = Request.GetFormField("email");
    hash = Request.GetFormField("hash");
    accountDE = DataExtension.Init("sfUserAccount");

      filter = {
       LeftOperand: {
        Property:  "emailAddress",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value:   email
       },
       LogicalOperator:"AND",
       RightOperand: {
        Property:  "Id",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value:   hash
       }
      };

    data  = accountDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter); 
    dataLength  = data.length;

    if (dataLength > 0) {
     FirstName = data[0].FirstName;
     LastName = data[0].LastName;
     Write(FirstName +'<br/>');
     Write(LastName); 
    }
</script>
```